# Expression “一...就...” - what if there is a sub-sentence?

Tags: grammar

---

**Example:**   我回家以后就预习功课。

**回答：** 我`一`回家`就`预习功课。

---

This structure is quite easy. However, how would we apply the same “`一`...`就`...” structure if there is an extra 'sub-sentence' in the example (i.e. **这一课很容易**).

What would be a grammatically correct answer then, to make it into a smooth whole?

---

**Example:** **这一课很容易**，我看了一会儿就懂了。

**回答：** ...❓

---

Would 我`一`看这很容易的课`就`懂了。 be correct?

Would 我`一`看**了**这很容易的课`就`懂了。 be more correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would 我一看这很容易的课就懂了。 be correct?

The sentence is grammatical, However, 这课我一看就懂 already indicated you think it is easy, adding "很容易的" make the sentence unnecessarily wordy.

You can add relative clauses in any part of the sentence as long as it makes sense:

这油画我一看就知是假的

这(标价三千万的)油画，我一看就知是假的

这油画(用的是二十世纪才有的油彩)，一看就知是假的

这油画，(身为画家的)我一看就知是假的 -